# WP SharpPDF NuGet Package

Tags: windows-phone-8, debug-mode, app-certification-kit, sharppdf

I have a problem when I use the *Windows App Certification Kit* with the `SharPDF-SL.dll`. The test fails and says

> The binary SharpPDF-SL.dll is built in debug mode.

I downloaded this library with `NuGet` so I can't rebuild the `dll` in release mode. Appreciate any help!

Comment: Looks more like issue to be sent on SharpPDF-SL dev team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this bug. I compiled it for WP8.1 Silverlight project. If someone have the same problem, I share my solution.

source code : https://mega.nz/#!HhNElRSa!9GJXQvII0p1K3EHK7Y1VeIOPWBBbCE-vUU3UdZNsD5w

release dll : https://mega.nz/#!6g8TmR6I!P3XOfSRLaiCLbgVZ1RHktPxKbUWVE77Z-MojngnSxiE